# How to deal with base non-virtual/non-abstract properties when need override and implicit class usage?

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual, abstract

I want to track `TopMost` property changes in my custom forms which are referred as `(Form)`. I cannot use `override`, because `TopMost` isn't `abstract` or `virtual`, I can't use `new` keyword because it has no effect while implicit referring.

What is the best way to deal with such a task? We can substitute any property instead `TopMost` as long as base class (`Form`) has neither "change"-event, nor ONSomething virtual method to override, and our property isn't marked as `abstract` or `virtual`.

Example:

I have many classes based on `Form`

```
MyForm1:Form, class MyForm2:Form, class MyForm_n:Form
```

Some "factory" returns instances of `Form` type

```
Form f = GetMyForm();
```

And finally i do

```
f.TopMost = !f.TopMost;
```

The deal is that I can't really use any other return type for `Form GetMyForm()`. I can't use `interface` or other base class except actual `Form` one (in fact, there is no factory, I use `.ParentForm` property of some control).

What is the best way to acheive task and keep my code as clean as possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example code doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem you describe in the first paragraph.  Are you asking how best to be notified of changes to a property that doesn't have a suitable event for that notification?  If not, can you clarify your question?

Comment: Can you change the code of the base class `Form` yourself, to make the property virtual and/or insert extra code in its setter and getter?

Comment: @dan sorry, wrong save. in a minute.

Comment: @DanPuzey I think you are close enough. I have some architectural  problem here, so I don't know exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try to put this short: I have to deal only with instances of basic Form and UserControl classes. Form contains UserControl. UserControl can change .ParentForm .TopMost property directly. And I need two-way connection: I have to update/notify UserControl instance when third party changes value of Form (.ParentForm) .TopMost property. Target Framework version is 3.5.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen No, just basic (might I say "native"?) Form class, because I retrieve instances from .ParentForm property and can't really refactor all the way up introducing new property with new return type, or performing some ugly type conversion like MyForm f = this.ParentForm as MyForm. I believe I miss something simple here.

Comment: @DanPuzey I lied again. I can use custom UserControl of course. It's just my Form never knows that it contains instance of some other class except UserControl, so it can't rely on that hypothetic MyUserControl properties and change values directly. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to introduce a new abstract class between your concrete classes and `Form`. That could have an `ObservedTopMost` property or something like that, which delegates to `TopMost` but also raises an event.

It's important to note that that this will *only* be useful when the new property is used; it won't magically spot changes to the existing property from elsewhere. It might be good enough for your purposes though.

Comment: No, can't do. I believe I messed up with snippets, so the best problem statement placed in my comments to original post. I'm sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @JohnSmith: In that case, the answer is simply no - you can't affect the behaviour of non-virtual members which are called from types which only know about the class that you don't have control over.